6.1810 / Fall 2023 Operating Systems Engineering Open Courseware. Lab: Xv6 and Unix utilities 'primes' question
I am trying to solve the following from https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.1810/2023/labs/util.html:

Write a concurrent prime sieve program for xv6 using pipes and the design illustrated in the picture halfway down this page and the surrounding text. This idea is due to Doug McIlroy, inventor of Unix pipes. Your solution should be in the file user/primes.c.

Here is a diagram showing how it's meant to work (from https://swtch.com/~rsc/thread/),
rectangles are processes, receiving and forwarding numbers
And I am mostly successful with the following code,
#include "kernel/types.h"
#include "kernel/stat.h"
#include "user/user.h"
#define PROCESS_MAX (int) 35

void extend_pipeline(int* pipe);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int pipefd[2];
  pipe(pipefd);

  // this is the generating process
  for (int i = 2; i <= PROCESS_MAX; i++) {
    write(pipefd[1], &i, sizeof(int));
  }
  extend_pipeline(pipefd);
  exit(0);
}

void extend_pipeline(int* pipe_parent) {

  int cpid;
  int pipe_child[2];
  pipe(pipe_child);

  int p = 0;
  int n = 0;
  close(pipe_parent[1]);
  int iteration = 0;

  while (read(pipe_parent[0], &n, sizeof(int)) > 0) {

    iteration++;
    if (iteration == 1) {
      p = n;
      sleep(1);
      printf("prime %d\n", p);
     }

    if (n % p != 0) {
      write(pipe_child[1], &n, sizeof(int));
    }
   }
  if (iteration == 1) {
    exit(0);
  }
  if ((cpid = fork()) == 0) { // child
    extend_pipeline(pipe_child);
    exit(0);
  }
}

However, the program doesn't terminate. I have to enter a newline before the shell prompts for user input. Therefore, I fail the tests.
The output of my code is:
$ ./primes
prime 2
$ prime 3
prime 5
prime 7
prime 11
prime 13
prime 17
prime 19
prime 23
prime 29
prime 31


When it should be:
$ ./primes
prime 2
prime 3
prime 5
prime 7
prime 11
prime 13
prime 17
prime 19
prime 23
prime 29
prime 31
$

Why doesn't the program terminate? I believe I need to add a wait call somewhere, but I am not sure.
I have tried putting a wait in the main function, but that only prints out primes 2, and 3 before hanging.

Is this really parallel? The poarent forks once and immediately exits. It looks like only one process runs at a time.

Not directly related to your problem: The #includes look strange. You should refer to the documentation of the functions for finding the correct header files to include. And check the return values of the functions. Many functions will indicate success or error by their return values.

The parent process terminates after extend_pipeline. I get a shell prompt at this time. A child process (or more?) stays running and prints results. I have to press Enter to get a new shell prompt, but this is normal behavior with background processes. I could as well type a command. Please [edit] your question and descibe in more detail the expected processes, their tasks and the communication between the processes. If possible add a link to the task description.

Another problem: Your main function writes to the pipe before creating the child process. This would block when the pipe buffer is filled completely.

@n.m.couldbeanAI I have edited the question to include a link to an image (and the source), showing how the primes are generated. I believe I am following that?
The lab specification says:
"You should create the processes in the pipeline only as they are needed."

@Bodo here is the open courseware lab: https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.1810/2023/labs/util.html

Please enable compiler warnings, fix them and show the updated code. See e.g. https://airbus-seclab.github.io/c-compiler-security/

"I believe I am following that?" Doesn't seem to be the case. The text describes several processes running at the same time, each reading numbers from its parent one by one, and sending numbers to its child. This doesn't happen with your code. You are writing to a pipe when no child is present. "You should create the processes in the pipeline only as they are needed" You should fork a child immediately before writing to its pipe (but not earlier).

You also fail this "the main primes process should only exit after all the output has been printed, and after all the other primes processes have exited".
